# Opencv python package manage

Tags: python, opencv, pypi

Recently I used opencv Python to handle Video Steam.
Normally I should install opencv-python via pip.
However I found that the opencv-python in pypi is unofficial package.
And it's just a package with opencv core, which does NOT including packages like contrib and FFmpeg...
If you wanted a version of opencv with extra packages, you should possibly download the opencv source code and build your own Opencv Python Bindings.

For me, this is not a friendly way to manage Opencv compared to other python libs in pypi.

Does anyone have a more elegant way to manage opencv python in both Mac and Linux OS please?

Comment: I used pip to install on Linux OS, it was so easy to install and manage. But for MacOSX, i prefer to install from here : https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/05/macos-install-opencv-3-and-python-3-5/
And i strongly suggest to do so. Why did you prefer unofficial way ?

Comment: `pip install opencv-contrib-python` for video support to install specific version use `pip install opencv-contrib-python==`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easies way to install opencv-python is [link](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/19/install-opencv-3-on-macos-with-homebrew-the-easy-way/) or this [link](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/19/pip-install-opencv/).

`pip install` will just install opencv-core, which does not include FFmpeg lib...

Answer (score 0):

if u have anaconda then just open anaconda prompt and you can try

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

or for opencv 3 version you can try

```
conda install -c menpo opencv3
```